# How to run project of React Native in other Android Emulator

Tags: react-native

I have an AVD but I just have 4gb ram so when I use AVD my laptop is really slow with the Google Chrome to research when coding. So I need to use other Android Emulator with high API too.

So my question is how can I run my app or the project of React Native in other Android Emulator? And what are some good emulator with high API that can connect it with Android 8.0 (Oreo) because React Native requires that version.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new virtual device in you AVD-Manager and give less ram to it. Otherwise you can try if genymotion gives you a better performance, but it should depend on the amount of ram you give to the emulator.